# FancyBox 2 not centered in viewport Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, fancybox, viewport

I'm using FancyBox 2 for a series of light boxes in a site and, while they're working great in Safari and Chrome, in Firefox the lightbox appears to be vertically centering itself based on the whole page height, not the visible viewport. The site can be viewed here:

http://xydemo.xylemdesign.com/Our-Story.php

I've downloaded a fresh copy of the script and it still isn't working.

The code being used to call the fancy box function is as follows. I'm using the latest version of the script, 2.1.5.

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({ helpers : { title : { type : 'over' } } });
```

A snippet of the PHP used to generate the gallery function of the page is as follows:

```
<li><a class="fancybox" rel="our_story" title="Greg checking out the west side shop floor." href="images/galleries/our_story_1.jpg"><img src="images/galleries/our_story_1_t.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
```

This error is occurring in all the different versions of Firefox that I can lay my hands on. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `backface-visibility: hidden;` from your `main.css`

Comment: That worked... thank you so much. Any idea why that would have an effect on the modal windows?